# How do you determine what files are associated with a label in TFS?

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am unsure if I have a bug or my understanding of labeling in TFS is faulty.  I have a situation where I have a file I expect to have a specific label assigned to it.

I have 2 projects, the main project and the 3rd party project.  I apply a label to both.

When I do a find for a specific version on one file in 3rd party project using the label search, the label appears.  If I use the label, I get an error that it can't find the label.

For the main project using the label always works.

Additionally, I see the label for file in projects I never applied the label too...

So at this point, I am trying to determine exactly what files do have my label and try to figure out why the label is present in search for everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have you tried opening Source Control Explorer, File -> Source Control -> Labels -> Find Label

Then just double click on the label you want to see.

[SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545785/how-do-i-figure-out-which-changeset-a-label-in-tfs-was-applied-to)

Comment: Ah!  It was teh double clicking on the label step I was missing.  So close, yet so far...   +1 for you.